# How can I simply validate whether a string is a valid IP in PHP?

Tags: php, validation

Using PHP, how do I validate that a string is a valid IP?

Examples of valid strings:

- 192.158.5.95
- 121.212
- 12.12.12.204

Examples of invalid strings:

- 121
- 10  12  12 (no dots)

My current script uses this code, but this is insufficient for my needs:

```
if(strpos($input, '.') !== false)
{    
  // There is a period 
} 
else 
{     
  // No Period 
}
```

As such, can someone please advise how I can validate that a string is a valid IP?

Comment: Please rewrite your question. It is gramattically gibberish at the moment, and would also benefit from using the rich text formatting functionality (e.g. code formatting). Furthermore, using an ellipsis ("...") implies impatience, which implies entitlement as though we should have already solved your problem for you by now. Might want to revisit that.

Comment: ya actualy i m new for this site so i haven't more knowledge but i think it's an excelent site

Comment: if i want to delete my this question then how it is posible bcause i have an ans for this question

Comment: @harison - You don't delete your question when you get an answer, you leave it for others to benefit from the knowledge.

Comment: @harison: ask, get answer, delete --- is not correct way to behave here ;-)

Comment: @harison - updated question to be a little clearer (I believe)

Comment: @zerkms u r right .. i know that it helps others ... but actualy i have an ans ...for this question ... thats why ... anyways thanks alots for my ans. & plz when i ask question then always help me .. bcause i m just the begineer in php ... chers !

Comment: @ Graphain actualy i don't no how to update the question in a better way like zneak edit my quetion in a beter way so plz help me how ?

Comment: @Graphain thanks u all r genious here chers

Comment: [click](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php) try to search online as Network function in PHP u can get more what u expect....
goood day dude..

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
$valid = ip2long($ip) !== false;
```

Comment: @Ozh: `200` is actually technically valid IP address `0.0.0.200`. There are restrictions that won't allow you to use it in real life (like a lot of other), but it still a valid IP

Comment: Actually, ip2long returns true for strings like "192.168.0355.24", which is not a valid ip now, is it? This might be a bug though, because with the input string "192.168.355.24" the function returns false as expected. However, one should be careful using the function as it is. The answer by iNaD provides a more solid result.

Comment: @para: why isn't it a valid IP? It **IS** a valid IP. Thanks for downvote. When you realize you're wrong - please undo it. Thank you. PS: even `2130706433` is a valid IP, try to ping it. PPS: if you still don't believe - open http://0313.109.178.99 and see it's a google

Comment: @zerkms Well, filter_var does filter it out, so I guess there must be some difference in what result you want to expect. If it is a valid IP, can you explain why filter_var filters it out? I will remove the downvote (as soon as it is possible, i am now getting an error because I voted 1 hour ago), but it would be nice if you could explain :)

Comment: @zerkms Just figuered that parts of such an IP is then interpreted as octal, not decimal numbers, so I guess that explains why it can be pinged. OK! :) Might be because one rarely uses octal numbers (leading zero), so I thought leading zero just does nothing, where in fact it describes the following as octal.

Answer (score 55):

Try it with [filter_var](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php)

**Example:**

```
if(filter_var('127.0.0.1', FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) !== false) {
    // is an ip
} else {
    // is not an ip
}
```

If you now have a string like `foo`, `127.0.0.bla` or similar, `filter_var` will return `false`. Valid IPs like `10.1.10.10`, `::1` are considered as valid.

**Notice**

Also you have to check on `!== false`, because `filter_var` returns the value, if it is valid and `false` if it isn't (e.g. `filter_var("::1", FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)` will return `::1`, **not** `true`).

**Flags**

You could also use some of the following flags:

> FILTER_FLAG_IPV4 (Filter for IPV4)
>
> FILTER_FLAG_IPV6 (Filter for IPV6)
>
> FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE (Disallow IPs from the private range)
>
> FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE (Disallow IPs from the reserved range)

`filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE)`

If `$ip` is `127.0.0.1` the function will return `false`.

**Notice** Awkwardly `::1` is ok for `FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE`, but `127.0.0.1` isn't.

Comment: Since I discovered filter_var I don't want to miss it. It's a reliable way (as far as I can say) to validate IPs, E-Mail addresses etc.

Comment: This worked well for me. Wish there was more filters for other network information validation.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case there's anyone that doesn't want to use the ip2long function, here is a simple function (Idea taken from a class in osTicket):

```
function is_ip( $ip = null ) {

    if( !$ip or strlen(trim($ip)) == 0){
        return false;
    }

    $ip=trim($ip);
    if(preg_match("/^[0-9]{1,3}(.[0-9]{1,3}){3}$/",$ip)) {
        foreach(explode(".", $ip) as $block)
            if($block<0 || $block>255 )
                return false;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: It is used to test if each part of the IP is within the correct range.

Comment: No but it one of the ways you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

iNaD ist right, the filter_var() version is the best one - ip2long() is *really* not that failsave. Just try to put in some strange things and see for yourself. I did a performace-check and filter_var is pretty much faster than the common regex versions.

Comment: Something like this should probably go in a comment. It isn't an answer.

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't a real answer like @php_coder_3809625 said. So Downvote.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$ip = "192.168.0.1";    
if(filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
{
  echo "IP is valid";
} else
{
  echo "IP is not valid";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If @Tomgrohl brought up regexes, you can do it in one line:

```
function is_ip($ip) {
    return is_string($ip) && preg_match('/^([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-5][0-5])\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-5][0-5])\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-5][0-5])\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-5][0-5])$/');
}
```

Explanation:

```
/ // regex delimiter
    ( // start grouping
        [0-9] // matches from 0 to 9
        | // or
        [1-9][0-9] // matches from 10 to 99
        | // or
        1[0-9]{2} // matches from 100 to 199
        | // or
        2[0-5][0-5] // matches from 200 to 255
    ) stop grouping
    \. // matches the dot
    // the rest (same) of the numbers
/ regex delimiter
```

Online tester: https://regex101.com/r/eM4wB9/1
Note: it only matches ipv4