# PHP and HTML form only allow IP address to be posted

Tags: php, html

I'm working on an basic HTML form like the one below.

```
<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="IP" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And a basic PHP script which will post all data in a TXT document like the one below as well.

```
$var = $_POST['IP'];
file_put_contents("/example/secretfile.txt", $var . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
exit();
```

Is there a way to restrict what a user is posting into the HTML form and have PHP validate that the only thing posted is an IP address? I don't want users to be able to post anything besides an IP. The IP does not have to be real or connect to anything. I'm quite new working with PHP so I don't know of a way to do this.

Comment: You are looking for a "regular expression" which allows to test a string against a complex "search pattern": http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I simply validate whether a string is a valid IP in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827435/how-can-i-simply-validate-whether-a-string-is-a-valid-ip-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `FILTER_VALIDATE_IP`:

```
$var = $_POST['IP'];
if (filter_var($var, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) === false) die('This is not a valid IP: ' . $var);
file_put_contents("/example/secretfile.txt", $var . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
exit();
```

See there for the possible flags (for example, whether IPv4 and IPv6 are accepted, etc.): http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php

Comment: It might make sense to also mention the available flags for this filter option since it is not clear _what kind of_ ip addresses the OP wants to accept.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I will be testing it out, should work for what I need it for.